# Autofac logging module & Resolved Parameter in ASP.Net Web Forms

Tags: c#, asp.net, webforms, autofac, nlog

I'm trying to use an Autofac module to inject NLog logger to asp.net **Web Forms** application (code behind) but i'm getting an error when trying to use a ResolvedParameter:

**Global asax & Logging module:**

```
public class Global : HttpApplication, IContainerProviderAccessor
{

    static IContainerProvider _containerProvider;
    public IContainerProvider ContainerProvider
    {
        get { return _containerProvider; }
    }

    void Application_Start(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        var builder = new ContainerBuilder();
        builder.RegisterModule<LoggingModule>();
        _containerProvider = new ContainerProvider(builder.Build());

    }
}

 public class LoggingModule : Module
 {
     protected override void Load(ContainerBuilder builder)
     {
         builder.Register(RegsiterFunc).AsImplementedInterfaces();
     }

     private NLogger RegsiterFunc(IComponentContext arg, IEnumerable<Parameter> parameters)
     {
         return new NLogger(parameters.TypedAs<Type>());
     }

    protected override void AttachToComponentRegistration(IComponentRegistry componentRegistry, IComponentRegistration registration)
    {
        registration.Preparing +=
            (sender, args) =>
            {
                var forType = args.Component.Activator.LimitType;

                var logParameter = new ResolvedParameter(
                    (p, c) => p.ParameterType == typeof(ILogger),
                    (p, c) => c.Resolve<ILogger>(TypedParameter.From(forType)));

                 args.Parameters = args.Parameters.Union(new[] { logParameter });
            };
    }


}
```

**NLogger class:**

```
public class NLogger : ILogger
    {
        private readonly Logger m_Logger;

        public NLogger(Type type)
        {
            m_Logger = LogManager.GetLogger(type.FullName);
        }

        public NLogger(string typeName)
        {
            m_Logger = LogManager.GetLogger(typeName);
        }

    .......
}
```

**Aspx page code behind:**

```
public partial class _Default : Page
{
    public ILogger m_Logger { get; set; }
    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        m_Logger.Error("test");
    }
}
```

To initiate the log based on the requesting type I'm using a ResolvedParameter.

The line **parameters.TypedAs()** in RegsiterFunc throws an exception: "Sequence contains no elements".

Same code works in asp.net MVC application but fails in the web forms project.

> System.InvalidOperationException occurred HResult=0x80131509
>   Message=Sequence contains no elements Source=Autofac
>   StackTrace: at Autofac.ParameterExtensions.ConstantValue[TParameter,TValue](IEnumerable`1 parameters, Func`2 predicate)
>   at Autofac.ParameterExtensions.TypedAs[T](IEnumerable`1 parameters)
>   at WebApplication1.LoggingModule.RegsiterFunc(IComponentContext arg, IEnumerable`1 parameters) in Global.asax.cs:line 55
>   at Autofac.Builder.RegistrationBuilder.<>c__DisplayClass0_0`1.b__0(IComponentContext c, IEnumerable`1 p)
>   at Autofac.Core.Activators.Delegate.DelegateActivator.ActivateInstance(IComponentContext context, IEnumerable`1 parameters)
>   at Autofac.Core.Resolving.InstanceLookup.Activate(IEnumerable`1 parameters)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As far as I understand, in `RegsiterFunc` you are attempting to retrieve type of component the logger is being injected into.

But the parameter that carries component type is not a `TypedParameter`, but rather it's a `NamedParameter`. That's why you get the exception.

Though less elegant, but working version of `RegsiterFunc`:

```
private NLogger RegsiterFunc(IComponentContext arg, IEnumerable<Parameter> parameters)
{
    var type = (Type)((NamedParameter)parameters.First()).Value;
    return new NLogger(type);
}
```

Then for Default.aspx page, the type passed to `NLogger` will be `ASP.default_aspx`.

The second parameter you create:

```
new ResolvedParameter(
    (p, c) => p.ParameterType == typeof(ILogger),
    (p, c) => c.Resolve<ILogger>(TypedParameter.From(forType)));
```

is not in use, so that overriding `AttachToComponentRegistration` is unnecessary.

Comment: Great solution, Your code is working. I thought that the type of "injected into" (source) component is only available at the AttachToComponentRegistration stage. Also you are using a NamedParameter but this parameter is not set it before using it. Is the type of the source component always automatically available as the first named parameter ?